# NSFileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL cannot invoke 'coordinateWritingItemAtURL'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to write content in `NSFileCoordinator`, but it's throwing an error.
I tried several ways but none of them worked.

My code:

```
private func saveValues(note :String){
    fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(presentedItemURL!, options: nil, error: nil, byAccessor: { (newUrl: NSURL!) in
        self.notes.addObject(note)
        let saveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.notes)
        let success = saveData.writeToURL(newURL, atomically: true)
    })

    fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(presentedItemURL!, options: nil, error: nil) { ( newURL :NSURL!) -> Void in
        self.notes.addObject(note)
        let saveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.notes)
        let success = saveData.writeToURL(newURL, atomically: true)
    }
    print("===##==> ",note)
}
```

Both of the above code failed.
[image]

Entire code looks -

```
import UIKit

class UpdateViewController: UIViewController, NSFilePresenter {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfInputField: UITextField!

    var fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator()
    var notes :NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var presentedItemURL: NSURL? {
        let groupURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.navigateproje")
        let fileURL = groupURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("notes.bin")
        return fileURL!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {    
        print("print ",tfInputField.text)
        lblView.text = tfInputField.text
        saveValues(tfInputField.text!)
    }

    private func saveValues(note :String){    
        fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(presentedItemURL!, options: nil, error: nil, byAccessor: { (newUrl: NSURL!) in
            self.notes.addObject(note)
            let saveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.notes)
            let success = saveData.writeToURL(newURL, atomically: true)
        })
        fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(presentedItemURL!, options: nil, error: nil) { ( newURL :NSURL!) -> Void in  
            self.notes.addObject(note)
            let saveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.notes)
            let success = saveData.writeToURL(newURL, atomically: true)
        }
        print("===##==> ",note)
    }

    var presentedItemOperationQueue: NSOperationQueue {    
        return NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it following -

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9301

```
  fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(presentedItemURL!, options: NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForMoving, error: &writingError, byAccessor: { (coordinator) in

            self.notes.addObject(note)
            let saveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.notes)
            let success = saveData.writeToURL(coordinator, atomically: true)
        })
```

the actual trouble was option type was nil , which must of type NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForMerging,

so even following works-

```
    fileCoordinator.coordinateWritingItemAtURL(presentedItemURL!, options: NSFileCoordinatorWritingOptions.ForMerging, error: nil) { ( newURL :NSURL!) -> Void in

        self.notes.addObject(note)

        let saveData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.notes)
        let success = saveData.writeToURL(newURL, atomically: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type in the `byAccessor` closure is declared as non-optional

```
func coordinateReadingItemAtURL(_ url: NSURL,
                    options options: NSFileCoordinatorReadingOptions,
                      error outError: NSErrorPointer,
                 byAccessor reader: (NSURL) -> Void)
```